# MIPS Mars4.5 saving the first number in an arithmetic term

Tags: math, mips, mars-simulator

Hello i have a problem with my MIPS code. I am trying to save the first number of an aritmethic term for later use but it is somehow not working. I am new to MIPS and still not really familiar with it. I have the function main: which takes a user input and calls handle_one_line: Which is the function I am currently working on. Main: looks like this

```
    main:
m_loop:
# Load address of line buffer and read new user input into it.
la $a0, line_buffer
li $a1, 8192
li $v0, 8 # read string
syscall

# Reset the cursor so that it points at the first character in line buffer.
la $t0, cursor_pos
li $t1, 0
sw $t1, 0($t0)

jal handle_one_line

# Repeat.
j m_loop
```

i have some other basic functions like advance_cursor and get_current_char(Returns the character that the cursor is pointing at right now $v0:current character)

handle_one_line is looking like this an all it is supposed to do is give me out the first number of the term. is_num checks if the char is a number and read_num should give out the number.

```
handle_one_line:
# Save return address because we are calling other functions.
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $ra,  0($sp)


is_num:

    jal get_current_char    #returns the current char in $v0
    li $t0, '0'     #stores the ascii value of '0' in $t0
    bltu $v0, $t0, notdigit #If current char Ascii value<'0'->notdigit
    li $t0, '9'     #stores the ascii value of '9' in $t0
    bltu $t0, $v0, notdigit #If value of '9'<current char value->notdigit
    li $v0,1        #$v0 = 1

        notdigit:
        li $v0,0    #$v0 = 0



read_num: 
    jal is_num      #check if current cursor position char is a digit       
    beq $v0, $zero, Zeichen #If its not a digit quit and go to Zeichen
    jal get_current_char    #returns the current char in $v0
    lb $t0, ($v0)       #load the current char into $t0
    la $s1, link_chars  #set $s1 to the buffer
    sb $t0, ($s1)       #store current character in the buffer
    addi $s1, $s1, 1    #link_chars pointer points a position forward
    jal advance_cursor
    j read_num
Zeichen:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ($s1)
    syscall
```

It should give out $s1 but it actually does nothing when i enter my input

Comment: Several questions arise.. 1) `handle_one_line` starts by pushing the current return address, but where is the corresponding pop? 2) Are `is_num` and `read_num` both part of `handle_one_line`, or are they separate functions? 3) If they are part of `handle_one_line`, why does `read_num` use `jal` to jump to `is_num`? 4) If that `jal` is correct, why is there no `jr $ra` in `is_num`? 5) Why does `is_num` occur before `read_num`, such that the `is_num` part always will be executed before you get to `read_num`? 6) Why is there an `li $v0,0` directly after an `li $v0,1` in the `is_num` part?

Comment: I suggest you make use of the debugging features in MARS to step through your code and inspect its behavior at runtime.